# How to handle tap events for an interactive watch faces with androidx.wear?

Tags: wear-os, androidx, watch-face-api, watchface

What is the correct way of handling **tap events** with the new **androidx.wear.watchface** libraries? I was doing this with the now deprecated **android.support:wearable** libraries without any problem with **Java** (using **onTapCommand**). Now, everything seems to be quite different, especially since the documentation and examples seem to be available only in **Kotlin**. Also, I can't find any example which properly shows how the functions are used.

The documentation mentions **setTapListener**, **TapListener**. And then there are the functions **onTap**, **onTapEvent** and **onTapCommand**. This seems very confusing.

Could somebody put here a small example? Or point me to a working example on the internet?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Implementing this seemed to work for me

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/watchface/WatchFace.TapListener

My code:

```
class WatchFaceRenderer(...): Renderer.CanvasRenderer(...), WatchFace.TapListener {

     override fun onTapEvent(tapType: Int, tapEvent: TapEvent, complicationSlot: ComplicationSlot?) {

        if (tapType == TapType.UP)
            // do something
        invalidate()
    }
}

class Service : WatchFaceService() {

    override suspend fun createWatchFace(
        surfaceHolder: SurfaceHolder,
        watchState: WatchState,
        complicationSlotsManager: ComplicationSlotsManager,
        currentUserStyleRepository: CurrentUserStyleRepository
    ): WatchFace {

        val renderer = WatchFaceRenderer(
            context = applicationContext,
            surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder,
            watchState = watchState,
            currentUserStyleRepository = currentUserStyleRepository,
            canvasType = CanvasType.SOFTWARE,
        )

        return WatchFace(WatchFaceType.ANALOG, renderer).setTapListener(renderer)
    }
}
```